# How to ensure the values i submitted with the request have saved in the required db table using jmeter?

Tags: jmeter

I want to check if 1000 concurrent users log in a website and register and provide payment details then for every User i wanna check the details submitted are accurate. Is it possible that i can add a JDBC request which can provide me the details for every user immediately after the request is complete. I know this would increase my response time but that is not an issue for us. Or is there any other better approach for this. I need to do a functional test where if 1000 users register than for all these users accurate details get stored.

Thanks
Charan

Comment: But is there any other way i can acheive? Any suggestions would help.. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Your approach makes perfect sense and is quite achievable with JMeter using JDBC and assertions.

Here's a good tutorial on DB tests with JMeter:
http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/build-db-test-plan.html

Here's a good JMeter video tutorial series that also covers assertions (checking for something and raising an error):
http://blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-tutorial-video-series